# Como puedo darle formato decimal a una columna en Excel con OpenXml y C#

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

Por favor, alguien sabe como puedo darle formato decimal a una columna en Excel con OpenXml y C#? Yo tengo un archivo Excel que tiene las columnas predefinidas. Este se llena con un SSIS, pero necesito luego darle formato decimal con OpenXML y C# (requerido de esta forma).

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Necesitaríamos ver el código que has intentado, o al menos cómo estas generando el excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes seguir este ejemplo para hacerlo [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97307/Using-C-and-Open-XML-SDK-for-Microsoft-Office)

y este seria el codigo para poder darle formato de decimal a una celda

```
var nformat4Decimal = new NumberingFormat
 {
  NumberFormatId = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(iExcelIndex++),
  FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("#,##0.0000")
  };
```